# Camera with gsm card and facebook client

Tags: smartphones, camera

I know that a good mobile phone does this, but I would like to have a camera-ish camera with real buttons, and that I do not need to download my pictures to my laptop but I could upload to facebook on the fly.

What is the correct search term for such a device?

GSM camera gave me surveillance video cameras.

Comment: Some cameras can upload to Facebook if they have Wi-Fi, is it acceptable? Or do you really need the camera to use a SIM card?

Comment: Yes that is a good idea for extending my search term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Samsung NX 300 can upload pictures to Facebook after you configure Wi-Fi, and presumably your Facebook username/password.

[image]
*Picture from https://globalnews.ca/news/785601/how-to-pick-the-right-wifi-digital-camera/*

[This article](https://itstillworks.com/cameras-upload-facebook-via-wifi-23238.html) talks about similar features in Canon and Nikon cameras, as well as in other Samsung models such as the affordable ST150F.